# Using Schematron to identify a space as first character in element

Tags: regex, xml, docbook, schematron, dita

Is it possible to write a schematron rule/assertion that will identify a space(s) at the start of an element?  I need a way to flag elements that begin with a space for *possible* removal of the space, but I don't want to forcibly remove such spaces via XSLT, etc.  Here's an example:

```
<section>
<paragraph> Here's some text.</paragraph>
</section>
```

Comment: Will they always be structured as follows: `<...> text<...>`? Can the solution be in [tag:bash]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Schematron uses XPath for assertions, so testing an element's string value for a leading space is easy:

```
  <pattern>
    <title>Paragraphs starting with a space</title>
    <rule context="paragraph">
      <report test="starts-with(., ' ')">
        This paragraph starts with a space: <value-of select="paragraph"/>
      </report>
    </rule>
  </pattern>
```

Comment: Thanks!  This asserts a space at the start, rather than reporting it, so I changed the <assert> to <report> and it works well.  (I may not have been clear, I'm looking to get rid of spaces when they don't belong.)

Comment: You're welcome.  If this helped (modulo report vs assert), please remember to [**accept**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Thank you.

Comment: I do have a brief follow-up though (sorry!).  After a bit more testing, I'm seeing that my validation runs into issues when there are more than one <paragraph> elements in the context of a single <section>.  I read up a bit more on starts-with, and I see that it retrieves a sequence of all matched nodes, which isn't allowed as the first arg. Is there a way to use this pattern to retrieve one match at a time?  Or am I approaching this completely wrong now...

Comment: Sounds like you'd really like the context to be `paragraph` rather than `section`.  If so, also adjust the `assert/@test` to be `starts-with(., ' ')`.

Comment: You're welcome.  I went ahead and adjusted the pattern to use a context of `paragraph` and a test against the string value of the `paragraph` per your comments.  Switched from assert to report too.